# Performance problems on Oracle (11) which are quite fast on SQL Server (2005)

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

at the moment i am moving a big table structure from SQL Server to Oracle, but I noticed that many queries which execute intermediately on SQL-Server Express (2005/2008) 1 to 1 translated in Oracle due really long (up to 15 / 20 mins).

Did somebody have a similar problem? Could there be configuration issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you add the same indices on the Oracle DB?

Comment: Table size and structure? Example of one of the queries?

Comment: I think you are going to have to post some more details, such as the specific queries, the query plans, etc...

Answer (score 2):

Oracle probably needs to gather statistics on the tables if you just loaded the data. SQL does that on it's own but in Oracle you need to do that yourself. Best to create a nightly job or so that keeps all that stuff tuned.

Another cause could be that in SQL the Primary Key is usually a clustered index. In Oracle the equivalent is Index Organised Table, but it does not default to that.

Look at the query plans to see what the issue could be, you can insert a picture of it in your question.

Rgds Gert-Jan

Comment: If you gather stats as a nightly job, you risk getting plan unstability. You need to be careful about that in production environments.